# How to escape Iterated loop Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, validation, iteration

### Hey there,

I recently started learning python and Since I knew a bit of JavaScript, I got a little head start to python that what most beginner learners have when learning python. Since I started learning python, I have been taking challenges and working on my own little project in the mean time. The current challenge I have right now is to make a password validator.

#### My problem:

I have spent well over 2 hours trying to figure out how to count the number of special chars and numbers in a string (password).
I still haven't perfected the counting but my main problem right now Is getting the function to print out the result

Right, so I have the counter here:

```py
def password_validator():
    password = input("Please input your password >>> ")

    for element in password:

        num_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',]

        for x in num_list:
            num_count = 0
            if element.count(x):
                num_count = 1
                if element.count(x):
                    num_count = 2
                    num_pass_strength = 1
                    if num_count == 2:
                        num_pass_strength = 1
                else:
                    num_pass_strength = 0
            elif num_count == 0:
                num_pass_strength = 0

        spec_chars = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '*',]
        
        for c in spec_chars:
            spec_count = 0
            if element.count(c):
                spec_count = 1
                if element.count(c):
                    spec_count = 2
                    if spec_count == 2:
                        spec_pass_strength = 1
                else:
                    spec_pass_strength = 0
            elif spec_count == 0:
                spec_pass_strength = 0
```

This basically counts the number of digits and special chars in the password.

This is the how I calculate the password strength:

```py
        add_strength = 0

        if num_pass_strength == 1:
            add_strength += 1
        if spec_pass_strength == 1:
            add_strength +=1

        pass_strength = add_strength
```

This adds one strength to the add_strength variable, and the pass_strength gets it's data from the add_strength variable aswell.

And this is what I think I am having trouble with:

```py
            if pass_strength == 1:
                is_weak_pass = True
            elif pass_strength == 2:
                is_medium_pass = True
            elif pass_strength == 3:
                is_strong_pass = True

        if is_weak_pass == True:
            print("Weak")
        elif is_medium_pass == True:
            print("Medium")
        elif is_strong_pass == True:
            print("Strong")
```

This is supposed to check the value of the strength and define a bool - variable for the the desired output.

My main problem right now is though, when I run the script and enter the a password,
it leaves me with an out put like this

```
Output:
Please input your password >>> &^%&^%
Weak
Weak
Weak
Weak
Weak
Weak
```

Could somebody please tell me what I have done wrong. It is really bugging me and I would even love to figure out something like this for my other project. Thanks

Full Code:

```py
def password_validator():
    password = input("Please input your password >>> ")

    for element in password:

        num_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',]

        for x in num_list:
            num_count = 0
            if element.count(x):
                num_count = 1
                if element.count(x):
                    num_count = 2
                    num_pass_strength = 1
                    if num_count == 2:
                        num_pass_strength = 1
                else:
                    num_pass_strength = 0
            elif num_count == 0:
                num_pass_strength = 0

        spec_chars = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '*',]
        
        for c in spec_chars:
            spec_count = 0
            if element.count(c):
                spec_count = 1
                if element.count(c):
                    spec_count = 2
                    if spec_count == 2:
                        spec_pass_strength = 1
                else:
                    spec_pass_strength = 0
            elif spec_count == 0:
                spec_pass_strength = 0

            add_strength = 0

            if num_pass_strength == 1:
                add_strength += 1
            if spec_pass_strength == 1:
                add_strength +=1

            pass_strength = add_strength
  
            if pass_strength == 1:
                is_weak_pass = True
            elif pass_strength == 2:
                is_medium_pass = True
            elif pass_strength == 3:
                is_strong_pass = True

        if is_weak_pass == True:
            print("Weak")
        elif is_medium_pass == True:
            print("Medium")
        elif is_strong_pass == True:
            print("Strong")


password_validator()
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see when you are setting these `is_` variables to `True`.

Comment: There is a lot of redundancy in the code, cleaning it up might help expose errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of redundancy and reassigning of variables within multiple loops which makes your code a little difficult to read (at least to me).

A couple of pointers to start:

```py
if element.count(x):
    num_count = 2
    num_pass_strength = 1
    if num_count == 2:
        num_pass_strength = 1
```

Here you you define `num_count = 2` and define `num_pass_strength = 1`, then immediately after run a test to see `if num_count == 2` only to define  `num_pass_strength = 1` again.

You have similar logic lines throughout the code.

This block can be simplified in two ways, depending on what you want to do:

```py
if pass_strength == 1:
    is_weak_pass = True
elif pass_strength == 2:
    is_medium_pass = True
elif pass_strength == 3:
    is_strong_pass = True

if is_weak_pass == True:
    print("Weak")
elif is_medium_pass == True:
    print("Medium")
elif is_strong_pass == True:
    print("Strong")
```

First, instead of defining `is_*_pass` to Boolean, only to test it once, you can just move the print statements into the if statements (I will show below). Second, as a python syntax tip in general, if testing a variable that is defined as a Boolean, you do not have to use `if variable == True:`, `if variable:` will return the Boolean value of the variable.

Another thing to keep in mind, especially when using open ended variables (i.e. there can be less than one or more than three numbers/special characters in the password), is to use `<=` and `>=` to ensure those extremes are accounted for.

Here is an edited version of your code that removes the redundancy but (I think) preserves your overall goal. There are other, probably more efficient ways to do this, this is just a reworking of your code with a similar style in mind. The change of `num_list` and `spec_chars` from lists of strings to strings is just a style choice, and has no effect on the outcome of the function.

It can be edited with different and/or statements if you want to determine strength of the password based on the number count and special character count separately.

```
def password_validator():
    password = input("Please input your password >>> ")

    num_list = '1234567890'
    spec_chars = '!@#$%&*'
    num_count = 0
    spec_count = 0
    for element in password:
        if element in num_list:
            num_count += 1
        if element in spec_chars:
            spec_count += 1

    pass_strength = num_count + spec_count

    if pass_strength <= 1:
        print("Weak")
    elif pass_strength == 2:
        print("Medium")
    elif pass_strength >= 3:
        print("Strong")
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, num_pass_strength and spec_pass_strength have not been initialized and these 2 variables are being assigned new values every time the for loop iterates.

```
def password_validator():
    password = input("Please input your password >>> ")

    for element in password:

        num_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',]

        for x in num_list:
            num_count = 0
            if element.count(x):
                num_count = 1
                if element.count(x):
                    num_count = 2
                    num_pass_strength = 1
                    if num_count == 2:
                        num_pass_strength = 1
                else:
                    num_pass_strength = 0 # this statement resets num_pass_strength whenever element is not in num_list
            elif num_count == 0:
                num_pass_strength = 0 # this statement resets num_pass_strength whenever element is not in num_list

        spec_chars = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '*',]
        
        for c in spec_chars:
            spec_count = 0
            if element.count(c):
                spec_count = 1
                if element.count(c):
                    spec_count = 2
                    if spec_count == 2:
                        spec_pass_strength = 1
                else:
                    spec_pass_strength = 0 # this statement resets spec_pass_strength whenever element is not in spec_char
            elif spec_count == 0:
                spec_pass_strength = 0 # this statement resets spec_pass_strength whenever element is not in spec_char
```

I would suggest simplifying the code as such to check whether element is digit or special character.

```
# Initialize your variables
num_pass_strength = 0
spec_pass_strength = 0
for element in password:

        num_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',]

        # check whether element is in num_list
        if element in num_list:
            num_pass_strength = 1
                
        spec_chars = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '*',]
        
        # check whether element is in spec_chars
        if element in spec_chars:
            spec_pass_strength = 1
```

As a side note, if you're looking to count the characters in a Python string, you can consider utilizing [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) as well.

Answer (score 0):

See below for a working version of what you are trying to do, built off of your original attempt. I think what would be good for you to do is to go through the solution and see how it differs and why your attempt came unstuck. Some problems that were in your attempt:

- `is_weak_pass` and other `is_` variables were trying to be called before they were set. for example, if the PW is medium then `is_weak_pass` never gets set and there will be an error because the line `is_weak_pass == True` will fail
- The loop over elements was too high nested, you needed to finish the loop over the elements before moving on to the later stages, in your example the printing stage for example happens for every element
- You had the code block:

```
if element.count(c):
 spec_count = 1
 if element.count(c):
  spec_count = 2
```

This doesn't make sense because the inner if block will always pass if the outer one does

- You had variables being set inside loops when they should have been set outside loops as counters, i.e. `num_pass_strength` needs to be set outside of your element loop

The solution below by all means isn't the only way to do this, but hopefully is and example of some of the problems you were running into and how to address them

```py
def password_validator(password):
  
    num_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',]
    spec_chars = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '*',]
    num_count = 0
    spec_count = 0
    for element in password:    
        
        for x in num_list:
            if element.count(x):
                num_count += 1
        
        for c in spec_chars:    
            if element.count(c):
                spec_count += 1


    num_pass_strength = num_count > 1

    spec_pass_strength = spec_count > 1

    pass_strength = 0

    if num_pass_strength:
        pass_strength += 1
    if spec_pass_strength:
        pass_strength +=1

    if pass_strength == 0:
        print("Weak")
    elif pass_strength == 1:
        print("Medium")
    elif pass_strength == 2:
        print("Strong")        

pw = '&^%&^%'
print(pw)
password_validator(pw)

pw = '1as'
print(pw)
password_validator(pw)

pw = '11234as'
print(pw)
password_validator(pw)


pw = 'asp'
print(pw)
password_validator(pw)

pw = '1$325^#beasp'
print(pw)
password_validator(pw)
```